# Convert string into a dictionary

Tags: node.js

I have the following piece of string: 'username=Tomas&password=123', I've tried to split the string into 2 parts then split it again to remove the equals sign but don't know how to load that into a dictionary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've split the components, you can split again inside [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and assign to the object. You could also do this in a `for` loop if you don't want to use `reduce()`.

```js
let str = 'username=Tomas&password=123'
let components = str.split('&')           // [ 'username=Tomas', 'password=123' ]

let dict = components.reduce((obj, comp) => {
    let [key, val] = comp.split('=')      // ['username', 'Tomas']
    obj[key] = val
    return obj
}, {})

console.log(dict)
```